# Does Debian apt-get upgrade has a way to specify the updates to make

Tags: debian, apt, apt-get, debian-bullseye

Looking at the `apg-get upgrade` options, I do not see a way to specify up to what Debian version to apply updates. For example, if I have Debian 10.0 currently, is there a way to say; "I would like to apply all updates up to 10.10 but not everything after that (currently 10.12 is the latest"?

Comment: I don't think so, but it's an interesting question!

Comment: You don't explain *why* you want to do this. See if https://snapshot.debian.org/ can help you.

Comment: @A.B - good point. Here is the hypothetical scenario: Currently, I am running version 10.0, from testing, I know that everything until 10.10 works fine, but 10.11 breaks my application. I would like to bulk apply patches up until 10.10 on every new workload that I spin up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no way to do this, and in general, this isn't possible.  APT gets a package source which specifies a particular release.  That release is going to be something like `buster` or `oldstable`, and not `10.10`.

All updates for buster in a released point release are applied to the `buster` package lists, so if a package has been updated in 10.12, it's likely that the 10.10 package won't even exist in the archive anymore, since unused versions are pruned when no release references them.

You could try to use snapshot.debian.org if you want to pin to a particular date, but be aware that if you do that, you won't apply important security updates, and therefore it would be irresponsible to connect that machine to the Internet since it won't be up to date with security patches.  It would, in general, be better to fix your software such that it works with the new software, especially since anyone else who uses your software will also probably have done the upgrade and need the fix as well.